# Left-Aligned <ul> Centered within Wrapper <div>

Tags: html, css, html-lists, text-align

The following ul is left-aligned and I'm trying to centre it within the #category_list div but I can't seem to get it right.

I think the problem is that the ul doesn't wrap around its content but expands to full width.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>


    #category_list {
        padding: 1em 0 2em;
        text-align:center;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    #category_list ul{
        padding: 0;
        display:inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #category_list li{
        display:inline-block;
        width: 13.75em;
        padding: 1em 0;
        margin: 0 .5em 1em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }

    #category_list h2{
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0;
        font: 1em "Georgia", Serif;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="category_list">
        <ul>
        <li><h2>Title</h2><img src="_images/categories/img.jpg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p></li>
        <li><h2>Title</h2><img src="_images/categories/img.jpg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p></li>
        <li><h2>Title</h2><img src="_images/categories/img.jpg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p></li>
        <li><h2>Title</h2><img src="_images/categories/img.jpg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p></li>
        <li><h2>Title</h2><img src="_images/categories/img.jpg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p></li>
        <li><h2>Title</h2><img src="_images/categories/img.jpg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: http://s17.postimage.org/xa0am2crj/centreleftlist.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so turns out the best way to achieve the effect I am after is to modify the li width with percentages and media queries rather than trying to get the ul width working correctly.

So something like this:

```
#category_list {
    padding: 1em 0 2em;
    text-align:center;
}

#category_list ul{
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#category_list li{
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 0 1% 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
    #category_list li{width:33%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 36em) {
    #category_list li{width:48%;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WegTf/) (jsFiddle) EDIT: (closest version: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WegTf/2)):

```
#category_list ul{
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#category_list li{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 13.75em;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 0 .5em 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

Basically the `text-align: left` was moved from ul -> li.

Comment: No that makes all the li's center-aligned - say you resize the window so there's 4 li's on top and 2 on a second line. I would like the 2 on the second line to align to the left not the center.

Comment: OK, so the first row centered, and 2nd one to the left, is that right?

Comment: No, all li's are left-aligned. And ul should be centred within the #category_list div.

Comment: So if you imagine creating box around all li elements (ul) - that is the exact width and height of the group of li elements. I would like that box to be centred within the width of its parent element (#category_list).

Comment: Added an image above for you.

Comment: No sorry. With the ul width at 80% it still doesn't perfectly centre because the total width of li elements aren't always equal to 80%. So in some cases on resize the there is an uneven extra space to right due to left-align.

Comment: You can achieve the auto-size via JavaScript. I'm not aware of solution via CSS. IMO you can't have all: auto-width, centering, flow without restriction (ie. width = 80%).

Answer (score 2):

The ul will expand to the width of its container unless you specify a width:

```
#category_list ul {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've decided it's easier to get the desired effect by editing the li width instead of the ul width.